# Getting com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am having one java application through which I am consuming one web service.

But surprising thing is that on a local machine I am able to consume that web service but same code does not work with our UAT machines and throws error

> Error :runtime modeler error: Wrapper class `com.iwave.operations.jaxws.IncidentGet` is not found. Have you run APT to generate them?

I really have no idea why it is happening.

It is working fine on some of the machines, but on few machines it is thrwoing the above error.

So any idea?

I am using jdk6u17.

Comment: Just to be sure, is UAT using the same version of java that you're using on your computer? If not, which version is it running? And are you using the same J2EE container on you computer and UAT?

Comment: Yes I already checked it is same version of java..

Comment: I resolved it by compiling classes manually..